# Haskell takeWhile but for list, not its elements

Tags: haskell

I have an infinite list which I'm concatenating to a string.

```
foldl1 (++) $ map show [1..]
```

What I'd like is to cut this string off when it has reached a length of ten characters or more.

However, takeWhile operates on individual elements of the list. Is there a function I can use to cut the list off when it's greater than ten characters?

In this case, I'd want the function to output "123456789", ignoring the 10, because going over would result in too big a length.

Edit: Here is my actual code. This does what I was describing.

```
succProd x = last. takeWhile ((<10).length) . scanl1 (++) $ map (show.(x*)) [1..]
```

Thank you!

Comment: The infinite list is in fact a bit more complicated than [1..]. This is merely an example. :)

Comment: Edit your question and add the real example.

Comment: Sure. I think this is much clearer and I already got the answer I needed, but alright.

Comment: @DanMaheshwari Can you please rephrase your question? It lacks the clarification that you want to do this while _building_ the list - I thought you were just talking about `take` for a while here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `scanl` instead of `foldl` to get a list of all the intermediate results, and take the last one you're happy with:

```
last . takeWhile ((< 10) . length) . scanl1 (++) $ map show [1..]
"123456789"
```

Comment: This recomputes the length for every single intermediate list. If performance is an issue, you can do something like `takeWhile ((< Sum n) . fst) . scanl1 (<>) . map (Sum . length &&& id)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `inits` to generate substrings from the beginning of the list, drop them while the criteria is not conveyed,

```
import Data.List
head . dropWhile ((<10-1) . length ) $ inits $ concatMap show [1..]
```

or

```
last . takeWhile ((<10) . length ) $ inits $ concatMap show [1..]
```

Comment: This is just another way of writing `take 9 . concatMap show`. Counting each element of `inits` is not interesting, because you know it increases in size by 1 each iteration. The problem in this question is how to entirely "discard" the last element that would cause the result to be too large. ie, if the list has "room" for one more character and the next number is 10, no more characters should be added, because 10 needs two characters.